# Decoding values stored in XDocument

Tags: .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have created an XDocument object containing some exception data, I want to save this to an XML file so that it can be reviewed when investigating errors:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(myCustomObject.SerializeToXml());
```

I've using the `Save()` method to save this data to file:

```
xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\myFile.xml", SaveOptions.None);
```

One of the nodes is output containing escaped characters (`&lt;` and `&gt;`), for example

```
<RootNode>
  <Name>My Object</Name>
  <DiagnosticInfo>
    &lt;DiagnosticInfo&gt;
      &lt;Processors&gt;
        &lt;String&gt;
          Something Something
        &lt;String&gt;
      &lt;/Processors&gt;
    &lt;/DiagnosticInfo&gt;
  </DiagnosticInfo>
</RootNode>
```

I've tried calling `HttpUtility.DecodeHtml()` on the "DiagnosticInfo" XElement but it is always output as escaped, any way round this?  Do I have to do something to the DiagnosticInfo element to tell it not to treat its content as a string?

The DiagnosticInfo element is the one that would be most useful so I'd like to have it looking proper when the XML file is opened.

**Edit**
In response to Jon Skeet's comment:

```
public string SerializeToXml()
{
    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(GetType());

    using (StringWriter w = new StringWriter())
    {
        s.Serialize(w, this);
        return w.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the problem is in `myCustomObject.SerializeToXml`, which you haven't shown.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - updated question. Thinking about it DiagnosticInfo is stored as a string in the object, would this be the issue?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Basically the XML you've shown is going to be the result of `SerializeToXml`, I strongly suspect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net serialisation uses reflection to decide what XML Elements to generate. These are based on the property names (like `Name`, `DiagnosticInfo`).

You mention DiagnosticInfo is an XElement. That means it is not a hierarchy of other objects, which is what you wanted, but rather it is a parser of XML elements and actually stores its XML as a string. When you serialise it you just get a single content value as a string.

You either need to parse/de-serialize your "info" into a more complex structure that actually contains properties like `"Processors"`, or write out the XML manually using an [XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfcy60y0.aspx) and `.WriteStartElement()`, `WriteEndElement()` etc

Writing it out manually, rather than trying to serialize it, is quite easy and would be my choice. The only unusual method you will need is [XmlTextWriter.WriteRaw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8563xyxa.aspx) which will stream out your raw XML in the middle of your other writes.